# I want cover lock screen my own app, but keyguard dont dissmise android 10

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to show my alarm activity, but when my activity started keyguard open fingerprint screen on Xiaomi mi8 miui 11. I can make click back button and I see my screen without unlock. But I want to see my screen right away above lock screen. But I get fingerprint screen first. myunlock code in activity onCreate():

```
   private fun allowOnLockScreen() {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setTurnScreenOn(true)
            setShowWhenLocked(true)
            val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
            keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, object : KeyguardManager.KeyguardDismissCallback() {
                override fun onDismissCancelled() {
                    super.onDismissCancelled()
                    Log.d("keygurd", "canceled")
                }

                override fun onDismissError() {
                    super.onDismissError()
                    Log.d("keygurd", "error") //when I make requestDismissError, I get error
                }

                override fun onDismissSucceeded() {
                    super.onDismissSucceeded()
                    Log.d("keygurd", "succeded")
                }
            })
        } else {
            this.window.addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            )
        }
    }
```

And my AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alarm">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"/>
  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:showOnLockScreen="true"
      android:showWhenLocked="true"
      android:turnScreenOn="true"
      android:excludeFromRecents="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
      <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".AlarmService" />
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Also I requested Overlay permission in onCreate():

```
   fun addOverlay() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                val intent = Intent(
                    Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
                )
                startActivityForResult(intent, 400)
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to start my activity from Service both with startActivity and with fullScreenIntent notification. No difference:

```
class AlarmService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        onHandleIntent(intent)
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("sdf", "sdf")
        val notification: Notification
        val notificationBuilder: Notification.Builder;



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val resultIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            // Create the TaskStackBuilder and add the intent, which inflates the back stack
            val stackBuilder: TaskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent)
            val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            val chan =
                NotificationChannel("my_service", "afadfs", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            chan.lightColor = Color.BLUE
            chan.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
            val manager =
                (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(chan)
            val notificationBuilder =
                NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "my_service")
            notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(com.example.alarm.R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Будильник")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                //.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) //intent
                .build()
            val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
        } else {
            notificationBuilder = Notification.Builder(this)
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Будильник")
            notification = notificationBuilder.build()
        }



        startForeground(1, notification)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            /*startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply { it show me my activity also
                flags =
                    FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            })*/
            Log.d("run", "run")
            val fullScreenIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            val fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "my_service")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEenter image description hereGORY_ALARM)
                .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)
            val notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)
            val notification1 = builder.build()
            notificationManager.notify(1, notification1)
            startForeground(2, notification1)
        }, 5000)

    }
}
```

What am I doing not right?
Miui 11 show me fingerprint first.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8cBf.jpg) screen fingerprint which I get when tried show my alarm activity.